# Nokogiri each node do, Ruby

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

**I have this xml:**

```
   <kapitel>
      <nummer V="1"/>
      <von_icd_code V="A00"/>
      <bis_icd_code V="B99"/>
      <bezeichnung V="Bestimmte infektiöse und parasitäre Krankheiten"/>
      <gruppen_liste>
        <gruppe>
          <von_icd_code V="A00"/>
          <bis_icd_code V="A09"/>
          <bezeichnung V="Infektiöse Darmkrankheiten"/>
          <diagnosen_liste>
            <diagnose>
              <icd_code V="A00.-"/>
              <bezeichnung V="Cholera"/>
              <abrechenbar V="n"/>
              <krankheit_in_mitteleuropa_sehr_selten V="j"/>
              <schlüsselnummer_mit_inhalt_belegt V="j"/>
              <infektionsschutzgesetz_meldepflicht V="j"/>
              <infektionsschutzgesetz_abrechnungsbesonderheit V="j"/>
```

How you can see my first node is  **kapitel** . I would like to do something like **kapitel**.each do |f| so that nokgiri extrakts the nodes von_icd_code  and bis_icd_code in the right order. My code:

```
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'nokogiri'   
    require 'open-uri'

 @doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("icd.xml"))

  kapitel = @doc.css('kapitel')
   kapitel.each do |f|
    puts f.css('von_icd_code')  
    puts f.css('bis_icd_code')  
   end
```

The problem is that nogiri does not extrakt the 'von_icd_code' and 'bis_icd_code' in the right oder, instead first it list all von_icd_code and then all 'bis_icd_code'. How can i extrakt the nodes in the right oder?

And in my output i get:

```
<von_icd_code V="A00"/>
```

How can i only get the content of the V in this case  **A00**

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `bis_icd_code` follows each `von_icd_code`, the obvious choice is css's `+` next adjacent sibling selector:

```
doc.css('von_icd_code').each do |icd|
  puts icd['V']
  puts icd.at('+ bis_icd_code')['V']
end
#=> A00
#=> B99
#=> A00
#=> A09
```

Comment: This relies on `bis_icd_code` always appearing *after* `von_icd_code` in pairs. They may well do that but there is no evidence of it.

Answer (score 8):

You can use Nokogiri's `traverse` method, which, well, traverses all the XML nodes in a recursive fashion.

Your example will then look similar to this:

```
names = %w(von_icd_code bis_icd_code)
@doc.traverse {|node| p node['V'] if names.include? node.name}
```

And it prints out

```
"A00"
"B99"
"A00"
"A09"
```

There's a lot of neat things in the `Nokogiri::Node` which allow us to do really cool things with even most complex XML files. For a short list of them, you can take a look [at this cheat sheet](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/wiki/Cheat-sheet).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, do you have some idee how i could solve my first issue, so that the nodes appear in the right oder?

Comment: They already do, if we change the code from `p node['V']` to `p node.name`, we'll have the nodes in the right order.

Comment: Sorry but i get the output text text icd_code ... ! My code:       names = %w(von_icd_code bis_icd_code)
 @doc.traverse {|node| p node['V'] if names.include? puts node.name}

Comment: Try this: `names = %w(von_icd_code bis_icd_code); @doc.traverse {|node| p node.name if names.include? node.name}`

Comment: I wouldn't say that traverse is an extravagance, but I agree that in this case it's the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

I'm sorry, this doesn't work with CSS selectors. Use XPath instead. And as for your secondary question, an attribute `V` of a node `node` can be accessed in Nokogiri using `node['V']`. Like this

```
kapitel = @doc.xpath('//kapitel')
kapitel.each do |f|
  f.xpath('//von_icd_code | //bis_icd_code').each do |node|
    puts node['V'] 
  end
end
```

**output**

```
A00
B99
A00
A09
```

---

You can fix this without the extravagance of `traverse` by writing

```
kapitel.each do |f|
  puts f.css('von_icd_code, bis_icd_code')
end
```

Comment: You say it doesn't work with css selectors, then you show that it does. Pick a side.

Comment: @pguardiario: The update, using XPath, works fine. The original, that uses CSS, iterates through all the `von_icd_code` elements and then through the `bis_ice_code` elements.